# camel-quartz2: clustering configuration

Tags: java, apache-camel, quartz-scheduler, load-balancing

I'd like to set up camel-quartz2 scheduler with clustering option.

Here's my current coding/configuration:

```
package com.foo.bar.quartz;


import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.EnableAutoConfiguration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;

@Configuration
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@ComponentScan({"com.foo.bar.quartz.camel"})
public class Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }
}

package com.foo.bar.quartz;

import org.springframework.boot.builder.SpringApplicationBuilder;
import org.springframework.boot.context.web.SpringBootServletInitializer;

public class ApplicationWebXml extends SpringBootServletInitializer {

    @Override
    protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
        application
            .showBanner(false)
            .sources(Application.class);

        return application;
    }   
}

package com.foo.bar.quartz.camel;

import org.apache.camel.LoggingLevel;
import org.apache.camel.builder.RouteBuilder;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;

@Configuration
public class CamelScheduler extends RouteBuilder {

    @Override
    public void configure() throws Exception {
        from("quartz2://group1/trigger1?cron=0/2+*+*+*+*+?&stateful=true")
        .routeId("quartztimer")
        .setHeader("ROUTING_KEY", simple("'trigger1'"))
        .log(LoggingLevel.INFO, "Yeah quartz rocks, routingKey: ${header.ROUTING_KEY}");

    }

}

org.quartz.scheduler.skipUpdateCheck = true
org.quartz.scheduler.instanceName = MyClusteredScheduler
org.quartz.scheduler.instanceId = AUTO
org.quartz.scheduler.jobFactory.class = org.quartz.simpl.SimpleJobFactory
org.quartz.jobStore.class = org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.JobStoreTX
org.quartz.jobStore.driverDelegateClass = org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.StdJDBCDelegate
org.quartz.jobStore.dataSource = myDS
org.quartz.jobStore.tablePrefix = QRTZ_
org.quartz.jobStore.isClustered=true
org.quartz.threadPool.class = org.quartz.simpl.SimpleThreadPool
org.quartz.threadPool.threadCount = 10     
org.quartz.jobStore.clusterCheckinInterval = 20000

org.quartz.dataSource.myDS.driver = com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
org.quartz.dataSource.myDS.URL = jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/cntmx?characterEncoding=utf8
org.quartz.dataSource.myDS.user = blah
org.quartz.dataSource.myDS.password = hlab
org.quartz.dataSource.myDS.maxConnections = 12
```

I duplicate this application into 2 separate projects and name them quartz-demo-1, quartz-demo-2.

I then run both applications on the same Apache server.

Both scheduler fires simultaneously at every 2 seconds:

```
2015-09-14 14:23:28 quartz-demo-2 [MyClusteredScheduler-camel-1-1_Worker-3] INFO  quartztimer - Yeah quartz rocks, routingKey: 'trigger1' 
2015-09-14 14:23:28 quartz-demo-1 [MyClusteredScheduler-camel-1_Worker-3] INFO  quartztimer - Yeah quartz rocks, routingKey: 'trigger1' 
2015-09-14 14:23:30 quartz-demo-1 [MyClusteredScheduler-camel-1_Worker-4] INFO  quartztimer - Yeah quartz rocks, routingKey: 'trigger1' 
2015-09-14 14:23:30 quartz-demo-2 [MyClusteredScheduler-camel-1-1_Worker-4] INFO  quartztimer - Yeah quartz rocks, routingKey: 'trigger1' 
2015-09-14 14:23:32 quartz-demo-1 [MyClusteredScheduler-camel-1_Worker-5] INFO  quartztimer - Yeah quartz rocks, routingKey: 'trigger1' 
2015-09-14 14:23:32 quartz-demo-2 [MyClusteredScheduler-camel-1-1_Worker-5] INFO  quartztimer - Yeah quartz rocks, routingKey: 'trigger1'
```

The desired behavior is that for every two seconds there should be only one firing from either application to simulate fail-over. How do I configure for such behavior? It seems both schedulers are not aware of each other even though they read from the same quartz tables.

Your help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two ways to fix this:

1) Define the propertiesFile property on the QuartzComponent. See **Configuring quartz.properties file** at http://camel.apache.org/quartz2.html

--or--

2) Run the second route on a different JVM. Here's why this fixes it:

This has to do with the JMX management name associated with the camel context. Looks like the Quartz2 component appends the management name (http://camel.apache.org/maven/camel-2.15.0/camel-core/apidocs/org/apache/camel/CamelContext.html#getManagementName()) to the name defined in the org.quartz.scheduler.instanceName property if you haven't defined the propertiesFile property as I described above.

See line 140 here:
http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.apache.camel/camel-quartz2/2.12.0/org/apache/camel/component/quartz2/QuartzComponent.java

Since you're running on the same JVM, the two camel contexts are getting assigned unique management names, resulting in unique scheduler names. This will prevent clustering from working as expected.

Comment: Thank you so much. I'm so grateful. I used solution 2). It works as expected now.